# C++ recvfrom doesn't receive all (binary) data

Tags: c++, linux, dns, binary

I'm trying to recieve a DNS request (DNS content with DNS header) in C++ on Linux 2.6.32. The code works when I write a string over UDP with netcat. But if I do a "nslookup google.com", it recieves only this:

```
root@EliteBook:/home/.../dns# xxd request.bin  
0000000: 8a2b 01
```

And if I use "tcpdump -x 'udp port 53' it shows me many bytes more.

My C++ code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFLEN 1024*6
#define NPACK 10
#define PORT 53

using namespace std;

void diep(const string &s)
{
        perror(s.c_str());
        exit(1);
}

int main()
{
        struct sockaddr_in si_me;
        struct sockaddr si_other;
        int slen=sizeof(si_other);
        int s;                                          // UDP Socket
        char buf[BUFLEN];
        buf[0] = 'X';
        buf[1] = 'Y';
        buf[2] = 'Z';

        if ((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP))==-1)
                diep("Failed to create socket!");

        memset((char *) &si_me, 0, sizeof(si_me));
        si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
        si_me.sin_port = htons(PORT);
        si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        if (bind(s, (const sockaddr*) &si_me, sizeof(si_me))==-1)
                diep("bind");

        for (int i=0; i<NPACK; i++) {
                if (recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, &si_other, (socklen_t*) &slen)==-1)
                        diep("recvfrom()");

                struct sockaddr_in *si_other_in = (struct sockaddr_in *)&si_other;

                cout << "Pkg arrived: " << buf << " " << inet_ntoa(si_other_in->sin_addr) << ":" << ntohs(si_other_in->sin_port) << endl;

                FILE * pFile;
                pFile = fopen ("request.bin","wb");
                if (pFile!=NULL)
                {
                        fputs (buf, pFile);
                        fclose (pFile);
                }
        }
        close(s);

        return 0;
}
```

Compile this with

```
g++ -Wall main.cpp -o dns
```

So, what is my fault, did I forget something or must I use an other call to read binary data?

PS: Localhost is the first nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf

**EDIT:**

I looket at the return value from recvfrom, and it shows me:

```
size: **27**
Pkg arrived: �. 127.0.0.1:36686
size: **45**
Pkg arrived: l 127.0.0.1:38952
```

That should be OK. Why does my buffer doesn't hold all bytes?

Comment: "*Why does my buffer doesn't hold all bytes?*" Your buffer **does** hold all of the bytes. You just aren't printing them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mostly ignoring the return value of [`recvfrom()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/recvfrom.html). That return value tells you how many bytes you received.

From the [man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/recvfrom.html):

> Upon successful completion, `recvfrom()` returns the length of the message in bytes

Without that information, you cannot know that you didn't receive all of the bytes.

> So, what is my fault, did I forget something or must I use an other call to read binary data?

You are *reading* the binary data just fine, but you are *writing* it incorrectly. Your call to `std::cout << buf` and your call to `fputs(buf, pFile)` each operate in character strings, not on binary data. Specifically, they each write the bytes up to, but not including, the first zero-valued byte.

To fix your program, record the answer from recvfrom, skip the call to `cout << buf`, and replace your `fputs()` with an `fwrite`.

```
// UNTESTED
for (int i=0; i<NPACK; i++) {
    int bufsize;
    if ( (bufsize = recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, &si_other, (socklen_t*) &slen))==-1)
        diep("recvfrom()");

        struct sockaddr_in *si_other_in = (struct sockaddr_in *)&si_other;

        cout << "Pkg arrived: " << bufsize << " " << inet_ntoa(si_other_in->sin_addr) << ":" << ntohs(si_other_in->sin_port) << endl;

        FILE * pFile;
        pFile = fopen ("request.bin","wb");
        if (pFile!=NULL)
        {
            fwrite(buf, 1, bufsize, pFile);
            fclose (pFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But I have it in a FOR-Loop, and it iterates only one time (seen on the std::cout output)